# Terminology for Statistics: top ½-percent as a '-tile'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, terminology, percentages

The top 25% is the top quartile.
The top 10% is the top decile.
The top 1% is the top percentile.

Is there a term for the equivalent for the top 0.5%, i.e. 1-in-200?

Comment: Top ***200-quantile***? You can see [*this*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) to know about the *q-quantiles* that have special names.

Comment: OK. Your ref to wikipedia suggests that the word does not exist. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the link doesn't have a special name for what you've asked for. That is why I gave my own suggestion as 200-quantile.

Comment: Actually, the top 1 percent is 99th percentile. We don't say top percentile, percentile is always rank ordered bottom to top.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could say a "half-percentile".

Comment: See my comment above, it would be ninety-nine-and-one-half percentile.

Comment: I would go decimal, for example, top 99.5 percentile.